# Is this possible to store sensor data in EEPROM and update that data into EXCEL file using Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, tkinter, esp32, eeprom

I am working with ***ESP32*** and **AHT25** sensor to get temperature and humidity values.
I want to store that temperature and humidity values in ***EEPROM***. I don't know much about storing data's in EEPROM. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

And also I need to fetch that data from ***EEPROM*** and update into ***EXCEL*** file. I am creating GUI using **Tkinter**. My need is if I create a button in my GUI like **DOWNLOAD EXCEL**, when I click this button the temperature, humidity data's from ***excel*** file (EEPROM Data updated in EXCEL File) should be download. I think it's a big process. Still I have no idea about how to do this. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have enough reputation for clarifying comments, I will try to present the task.
There are two temperature and humidity sensors, there is an EEPROM device. I can only assume that this is an arduino.
We need the sensor data to get into excel.

EEPROM has 10,000 to 100,000 rewrite cycles. It will just block after a while.
Therefore, we will not write anything into it.

I would send data directly to the computer via the COM port.
step by step:

1. take the documentation for the sensors and look at which register they write the values in, or is there a ready-made library for these sensors
2. we write c++ code that takes data from sensors and send it to Serial (rs232 is another name in windows -  com)
3. write python code that will connect to the com port on windows and listen
4. we write the incoming data as a csv file
5. if necessary, we load data from the excel program

When it works, you can add a graphical interface